# How to save or log pytorch model using MLflow?

Tags: pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

I am in `main.py` at the root directory at `main.py` calling the model script to train the model. The directory looks like this

[image]

After training the model, I am planning to save and log the PyTorch model using MLflow. Here’s the code

```py
# Registering the model to the workspace
    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(
        pytorch_model= model,
        registered_model_name="use-case1-model",
        artifact_path="use-case1-model",
        input_example=df[['Title', 'Attributes']],
        conda_env=os.path.join("./dependencies", "conda.yaml"),
        code_paths="./models"
        ]

    )

    # Saving the model to a file
    mlflow.pytorch.save_model(
        pytorch_model= model,
        conda_env=os.path.join("./dependencies", "conda.yaml"),
        input_example=df[['Title', 'Attributes']],
        path=os.path.join(args.model, "use-case1-model"),
        code_paths="./models"
    )
```

But I am getting an error while saving the code paths, saying the directory is not found.

Question 1: is there a need to save the code paths and extra files parameter in my case?

Question 2: What's the right way to save the code paths directory?

https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pytorch.html

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76322238/edit). It covers directory listings as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per function definition, the parameter **code_paths** is for giving a list of local filesystem paths to Python file dependencies (or directories containing file dependencies).

If your model having such kind dependencies you need to provide there paths in list to **code_paths**.

The error you are getting about directory not found can resolved by taking abs path as below.

```
code_pth = os.path.abspath("")+"/media/model/"
conda_env = os.path.abspath("")+"/dependencies/"
print(conda_env)
print(code_pth)
```

[image]

I have used sklearn model to log and save.

```
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(
sk_model=clf,
registered_model_name=registered_model_name,
artifact_path=registered_model_name,
code_paths=[code_pth],
conda_env=os.path.join(conda_env, "conda.yaml")
)
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

```
mlflow.sklearn.save_model(
sk_model=clf,
path=os.path.join(registered_model_name, "trained_model"),
code_paths=[code_pth],
conda_env=os.path.join(conda_env, "conda.yaml")
)
```

Output:

[image]